# storing results into a file after multiple runs python

Tags: python, file, output, executable

I have made an executable script in Python which takes as a command line argument the name of a file. The script runs and outputs a number. I have several files for which I have to run the script and I want to store all the results in a separate file called `results.txt`. The file should look like this:

```
name_of_file_1 result_number_1
name_of_file_2 result_number_2
name_of_file_3 result_number_3
...
name_of_file_n result_number_n
```

This is what I tried so far, but every time the name of the file and the result are overwritten.

```
args = sys.argv[1]
f = open('results.txt', 'w')
f.write(args + " " + str(len(i)) + "\n")
f.close()
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `append` mode instead of the `write` mode as follows:

```
f = open('results.txt', 'a')
f.write(args + " " + str(len(i)) + "\n")
f.close()
```

The `append` mode adds on to the existing file whereas the `write` mode simply clears the file or overwrites it.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
f = open('results.txt', 'a')
```